# The sheaf of derivations

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $ R $ be a commutative ring. Let $ (X,\mathscr O_X) $ be a ringed space over $ R $, that is, let $ X $ be a topological space and let $ \mathscr O_X $ be a sheaf of $ R $-algebras on $ X $.

A *derivation* on $ X $ is a morphism $ D\colon \mathscr O_X\to \mathscr O_X $ of sheaves such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_U(\alpha f + \beta g) &= \alpha D_U(f) + \beta D_U(g)\\
D_U(fg) &= gD_U(f) + fD_U(g)
\end{aligned}
$$
for any open subset $ U\subset X $, $ \alpha,\beta\in R $ and $ f,g\in \mathscr O_X(U) $.

Define a presheaf $ \mathrm{Der}_{X} $ on $ X $ by
$$
\mathrm{Der}_X(U) = \left\{\text{all the derivations $ D\colon \mathscr O_X{\restriction_U}\to \mathscr O_X{\restriction_U} $}\right\}
$$
for any $ U\subset X $ open, where the restriction maps are the obvious ones and where $ \mathscr O_X{\restriction_U} $ is the obvious restriction of the structure sheaf of $ X $.

I'm trying to show that this guy is a *sheaf*. But I'm stuck.

Comment: There are two things you have to verify, right? How far did you get on each of them?

Comment: Another possible approach is to use the following fact: Suppose $\mathscr{F}'$ is a subpresheaf of a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, and every section of $\mathscr{F}$ which is locally in $\mathscr{F}'$ is in fact in $\mathscr{F}$.  (The latter condition in more detail: whenever $x \in \mathscr{F}(U)$, and you have an open cover $\{ V_i \mid i \in I \}$ of $U$ such that $x |_{V_i} \in \mathscr{F}'(V_i)$ for each $i$, then $x \in \mathscr{F}'(U)$.)  Then $\mathscr{F}'$ is a sheaf.

Comment: So in this case, show that $\operatorname{Der}_X$ is a subpresheaf of $\mathscr{Hom}_{\mathsf{Ab}(X)}(\mathscr{O}_X, \mathscr{O}_X)$.

Comment: Ok I learned about the internal-hom sheaf during the Christmas holidays and now it's all clear. Thanks!